# Настройка рингтона, выбор источника по-умолчанию

Tags: android

Вопрос не по программированию. Для смены рингтона на звонки выбрал "**Хранилище мультимедиа**" здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И затем случайно вместо "Только сейчас" нажал "**Всегда**". Теперь для выбора мелодии доступен только такой выбор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Облазил все настройки, но нигде не могу найти, как сбросить выбранное действие по-умолчанию для выбора рингтона.
Что сделать, чтобы Android снова начал предлагать выбор "Только сейчас" и "Всегда"?

Comment: А гугл молчит штоль? если нажал "использовать всегда" и хочешь изменить это, то заходи в настройки, находи ту прогу на которой нажал "всегда" нажимаешь на нее, листаешь ниже, там увидишь "удалить настройки по умолчанию" удаляешь и все....

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что в списке всех приложений программы под названием "Хранилище мультимедиа" нет! А так, я первым делом это делал, прежде чем писать вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Входите в "Настройки", выбираете "приложения".
В правом верхнем углу жмете на три вертикальные точки и из подменю выбираете "показать системные приложения".
Выбираете "Хранение мультимедиа" нажимаете и открывается меню, там в "Настройках приложения находите пункт "Использовать по умолчанию", нажимаете на него и он становиться неактивным. После этого опять появиться выбор места хранения звуковых файлов.